# My code works on IDLE but fails on Pycharm or Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, pycharm

This is my code it runs in IDLE but it doesn't in Pycharm neither Visual Studio. Would you please help on this issue

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img=cv2.imread('1.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What's the error output?

Comment: I found my problem it was the 1.jpg which it was not correctly addressed 
thank you for your intention